# Unable to update the option for a select in safari for protractor with angular 2

Tags: protractor, angular-cli, angular2-testing, safari-web-inspector

I am working on automation using protractor for one of angular 2 application.
I am able to get the option element what I want to select for a drop down.

Note: I have tried many different ways to get the option from DOM.

But I couldn't able to select it using `click()` method on `WebElement`.
The `click()` is working in chrome but not in safari.
Tried with `browser.sleep()`,`ActionSequences`,`waitForAngular()` etc..
But none has worked.

example code snippet:

```
     element(by.css('#country')).$('[value="1"]').click();
```

or

```
     element(by.css('#country')).filter(function (elem, index) {
        return elem.getText().then(function (text) {
        return text.indexOf('USA') !== -1;
     });}).first().click();
```

As I said earlier, I have used many ways to get the element what I want.
But I am unable to select or click the option in safari browser.

Safari Version: 10.0.2
Mac Version: OS EI Captain 10.11.6

Comment: is it a plain dropdown `<select><option value="1">Value 1</option></select>`, or a styled one? If it's the last then can you give a code example of the dropdown?

Comment: Yes. It is a plain one.

`<select id="country"><option value='USA'>USA</option><option value='NL'>Netherlands</option></select>`

Like wise I have 230 countries listed in that select.

Comment: any idea on this? @wswebcreation.

Comment: Is the element actually found? Also you might try [`cssContainingText`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText).

Comment: @Will, tried that too. I am able to get the element for sure.

Comment: @Will , Can you guys help me in providing a working example for safari drop down selection if you have any?